# import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty; not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, import

I currently have a java/spring-boot application where I changed the version (in code) from 2.1.4 to 2.3.0 but as a result I've come across the error `error: package javax.validation.constraints does not exist` when trying to run a clean build - this comes from a `import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;` line I have in my code - does anyone know how to resolve this issue to the code compiles/builds successfully?

Comment: Have you seen [this part of the Spring Boot 2.3 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters) ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Validation Starter dependency is no longer included in the web starter dependencies. Therefore you need to add it manually to your gradle file:

```
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
```

This is mentioned in the release notes:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3.0-M1-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters