# @NotBlank, @NonNull not validating for the string "name"

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I am a newbie in Spring-boot and was learning to validate constraints, here the **@NotBlank**, **@NonNull** doesn't seem to work. What I want is to provide bad request for the null value given. Am I missing something here?

The snippet of model class has been given below:

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {
    private final UUID id;
    @NotBlank
    private final String name;

    public Person(@JsonProperty("id") UUID id,
                  @JsonProperty("name") String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

    }
```

And the controller class is given below:

**PersonController.java**

```
@PostMapping
    public void addPerson(@Valid @NonNull @RequestBody Person person) {
        personService.addPerson(person);
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What's the fully-qualified name of `NotBlank`? The Bean Validation name for the other one is `Nonnull`, so you have at least one nonstandard annotation involved.

Comment: Also please provide information about the request you've sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the **pom.xml** file.

About the validation part: The Validation Starter dependency is no longer included in the web starter dependencies (source: [check][1])

Select it when creating the Spring Boot config or just add at the **pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

[1]: [import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty; not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151650/import-javax-validation-constraints-notempty-not-working))